# Alfresco maximum and minimum length of default property like cm:name, cm:title

Tags: alfresco

I want to get the alfresco maximum and minimum length of default property cm:name, cm:title, cm:description, cm:modified and cm:modifier which are showed in Advanced Search page.

I know property constraint can be given using Content Model Constraints. http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Model_Constraints But I don't found for default property.

Can anyone give me hints or explanation for that??

Answer (score 1):

The limitation of the field size for d:text will be decided by the column type of your database.

For example, if you're using an Oracle database with d:text mapping to a varchar2 column [data type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm), you will have a maximum of 4000 bytes. That doesn't mean a length of 4000 characters. Alfresco requires UTF-8 encoding which means [each character will take up 1-4 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049139/do-certain-characters-take-more-bytes-than-others).

Updated: 9/29/2016 Corrected this answer.