# Maximum input and output length for Argon2

Tags: hash, argon2-ffi

As you may know, maximum input length for `bcrypt` is 72 characters and the output length is 60 characters. (I've it tested in `PHP`. Correct me if I'm wrong)

I want to know maximum input length and the exact output length for `argon2`. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2

Comment: @JamesKPolk I've read that. Didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2#Algorithm max input length is 2^32-1 bytes or 4294967295 bytes.

As to the equivalent in character length, it depends on what character encoding you use.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049225/9847511):

- In ASCII or ISO 8859, each character is represented by one byte
- In UTF-32, each character is represented by 4 bytes
- In UTF-8, each character uses between 1 and 4 bytes
- In ISO 2022, it's much more complicated

Still according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2#Algorithm I cannot give you an 'exact' output length because it depends on the length you choose for various parameters such as the salt and the output hash itself.

Comment: The Wiki link shows that the output length of the algorithm is linearly proportional to the `tagLength` input, in bytes. Presumably, the OP will know which character encoding they're using, but it's likely that in most cases, it's UTF-8.

Comment: Looks like the most common safe max file size for input encoded in UTF-8 will be about 1 gigabyte, given 4.3 gigabyte divided by 4 ≈ 1.1 gigabyte. So more than enough for most use cases except video and multimedia contents.

Comment: Note that the `argon2` command line tool [limits input to a maximum of 127 bytes](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2/issues/339).